# Is there some way to make this flex box (and the items inside) centered?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am attempting to make the nav bar. For some reason, there is some padding (as noted by chrome's inspect (or so I think?)) But I can't seem to find it in the css file, any tips? I may be doing the flex boxes wrong, but maybe something else.

[screen shot of the website (hosted locally)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pClAN.png)

```css
.header-nav {
  background-color: #E1D7C6;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

li {
  display: block;
  background-color: #D5BDAF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="header-nav">
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="what-we-do.html">What We Do</a></li>
    <li><a href="get-involved.html">Get Involved</a></li>
    <li><a href="donate.html">Donate</a></li>
    <li><a href="get-help.html">Get Help</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I tried to remove the other padding, spaces, and other text to see if something was causing it there. Any help/advice is appreciated! Thanks for the help!

Comment: _"But I can't seem to find it in the css file"_ - it's not coming from _your_ CSS "file". `ul` has a default padding-left coming from the _user-agent stylesheet_. Just overwrite it with 0 in your own CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your padding to 0, to get rid the 40px right-padding of .header-nav.

You should also use space-around, not between to create a little space in the start and the end of the navbar, and add a gap(i used 10px) betweet the flex items

```css
.header-nav {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #E1D7C6;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

li {
  display: block;
  background-color: #D5BDAF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="header-nav">
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="what-we-do.html">What We Do</a></li>
    <li><a href="get-involved.html">Get Involved</a></li>
    <li><a href="donate.html">Donate</a></li>
    <li><a href="get-help.html">Get Help</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Hope that helps